# Select list items by class and wrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, nested, html-lists, wrapall

I'm looking for wrap a list items in this situation.

```html
<ul class="subNav" style="top: 160px;">
  <li class="level2 nav-3-1-1 first 3">3</li>
  <li class="level2 nav-3-1-2 W">W</li>
  <li class="level2 nav-3-1-2 W">W</li>
  <li class="level2 nav-3-1-3 V">V</li>
  <li class="level2 nav-3-1-4 T">T</li>
  <li class="level2 nav-3-1-5 T">T</li>
  <li class="level2 nav-3-1-6 T">T</li>
  <li class="level2 nav-3-1-2 W">W</li>
  <li class="level2 nav-3-1-7 S">S</li>
  <li class="level2 nav-3-1-8 S">S</li>
  <li class="level2 nav-3-1-9 S">S</li>
  <li class="level2 nav-3-1-10 S">S</li>
  <li class="level2 nav-3-1-11 R">R</li>
  <li class="level2 nav-3-1-20 L">L</li>
  <li class="level2 nav-3-1-42 A">A</li>
  <li class="level2 nav-3-1-43 A">A</li>
  <li class="level2 nav-3-1-44 Y">Y</li>
</ul>
```

This HTML is products of cms.

I need to wrap all li with the same alphabetic letter class with jQuery.

This is what I want:

```html
<ul class="subNav" style="top: 160px;">
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li class="level2 nav-3-1-2 W"></li>
      <li class="level2 nav-3-1-3 W"></li>
      <li class="level2 nav-3-1-4 W"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li class="level2 nav-3-1-5 T"></li>
      <li class="level2 nav-3-1-6 T"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li class="level2 nav-3-1-7 S"></li>
      <li class="level2 nav-3-1-8 S"></li>
      <li class="level2 nav-3-1-9 S"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li class="level2 nav-3-1-11 R"></li>
      <li class="level2 nav-3-1-20 R"></li>
      <li class="level2 nav-3-1-42 R"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li class="level2 nav-3-1-43 A"></li>
      <li class="level2 nav-3-1-44 A"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I do this?

<sup><sup>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/urbanistFiddle/atzggckv/)</sup></sup>

Comment: So what happens to `<li class="level2 nav-3-1-1 first 3">3</li>` and few others??

Comment: Sorry, is an example, there are more li in my project with all alphabet. In case is a number, i can add "num-" + number.
<li class="level2 nav-3-1-1 first num-3">3</li>
And in jQuery select all class start with "num" instead off letter.

Comment: My question is, some `<li>` in your sample is not there in your desired output. Is it okay if the answer ignores few `<li>` as well? if not, please correct it and update the question properly.

Comment: Yes ignore it, you can use the html in the fiddle :)